# is it possible let line chat bot get string from otherplace?

Tags: python

I try to make a chat bot that can get ifttt message and send by it,but how should I make ifttt message string return to line chat bot ?
is it any idea can let line chat bot get string from somewhere?

Comment: Can you be more specific and provide an example of what you are talking about?

Comment: Try like `webhook`

Comment: @AeroBlue
i trying let line bot to get a message(string) from otherplace ,but i have no idea how I let line bot catch the message(string) from other place

Comment: @SmartManoj i using webhook,but I don't know how to let webhook get string from other places 
be more specific, ifttt will send a message by Line Notify,but i want my chat bot can get the ifttt message(string) and resend to other user

Comment: make-a-web-request from ifttt